# Telethon как избежать бана

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Кратко опишу суть проблемы: скрипт должен найти контакт в телеграме по номеру телефона. Этот контакт нужен будет для регистрации в боте. Ведь сейчас я все это делаю вручную. Я сделал скрипт, который должен искать контакты по номеру, но он блокирует аккаунты.

вот фрагмент, функция поиска контакта(номер телефона берется с таблицы):

```
async def find_contact(workbook, client):
    sheet = workbook['Sheet1']

    last_non_empty_row = check_last(sheet)

    for row_num in range(last_non_empty_row, sheet.max_row + 1):
        time.sleep(10 + random.randint(1, 2) * random.randint(-1, 1))
        phone_number = sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=1).value
        contact = await check_telegram_registration(client, phone_number)

        print(phone_number)

        if contact:
            if "last_name" in contact and contact["last_name"]:
                sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2,
                           value=f'{contact["first_name"]} {contact["last_name"]}')
                print(
                    f'Контакт знайдено - {contact["first_name"]} {contact["last_name"]}')
                await change_profile_info(
                    client, contact["first_name"], contact["last_name"])
            elif "first_name" in contact and contact["first_name"]:
                sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2,
                           value=contact["first_name"])
                print(f'Контакт знайдено - {contact["first_name"]}')
                await change_profile_info(client, contact["first_name"], '')

            save_excel_file(workbook, workbook_name)
            return
        else:
            sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2, value=False)
```

Я пока не сильно эксперементировал, так как нужно тратить на это ресурс, но  на уме пока есть несколько вариантов:

- использовать прокси гео аккаунта
- дать полежать неделю-две, чтобы появился траст/отлега
- увеличить кд запросов, рандомизировать их
- использоваать другую библиотеку

Что из вышеперечисленного поможет? Что посоветуете? Я хочу найти наиболее оптимальное решение. Я так думаю, блокировка происходит, из-за того что сам телетон апи палит меня, по-этому я хз как автоматизировать все это дело.

Comment: Происходит именно бан аккаунта или просто вылет сессии телеграм?

Comment: Наверное блокируется аккаунт

Comment: Можно поподробнее, как это происходит? Что происходит с аккаунтом/сессией на другом устройстве?